# Mediaplayer is stopped by AsyncTask - MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I start my app by downloading new files, if there are any there starting a playback loop. I then fire a task to look for new media every x seconds. As soon as the task is called, the video stops playing with the error **MediaPlayer finalized without being released**.

*Its supposed to download new media if there are any, and just update the playList.*

From what its logging I can see the first play is called, then after that the error comes up and then. It justs calles the task again and again. Its like its stuck in there?

Im sure this is some dumb issue that Im missing here. Im not sure why the mediaplayer is stopping?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

    int playListIndex;
    int currentMedia;
    String mediaName;
    ArrayList<Integer> playList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    File[] filelist;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    Uri mediaPath;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private SurfaceHolder holder;


//  Get this shit from login!
    public String channelid = "5e6299eb-asd6600d58fc9";
    public String username = "tvasd";
    public String linkid = "70casd6600d3f7d7";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

//      File mediadir = getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//        filelist = mediadir.listFiles();
        try {
            downloadMedia(this);
            updateMediaTask(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//       Delete all files in folder
//        if (mediadir.isDirectory()) {
//            String[] children = mediadir.list();
//            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
//                new File(mediadir, children[i]).delete();
//            }
//        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.i("media player", "play next please!");
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
        }
//      play next video
        currentMedia++;
        if (currentMedia > playList.size() - 1) {
            currentMedia = 0;
        }
        Log.d("MEDIA_COUNTER", String.format("%d", currentMedia));
        try {
            playMedia(currentMedia);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void playMedia(int playListIndex) throws IOException {
        Log.i("media player", "play media!");
        String path = filelist[playListIndex].getAbsolutePath();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        String filename = filelist[playListIndex].getName();
        Log.i("FILENAME", path);
        if (filename.contains("image")) {
            imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setImageURI(uri);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
                    onCompletion(null);
                }
            }, 4000);
        } else if (filename.contains("video")) {

            Log.d("PLAY",String.format("%s", fileInputStream.getFD()));
            Log.i("media player", "play video!");
            SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
            holder = surface.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    Log.i("SURFACE", "Created");
                }
                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
            });
            MediaPlayer pl = new MediaPlayer();
            pl.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            pl.setDisplay(holder);
            pl.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
            pl.prepare();
            pl.start();
        }
    }



    void createPlayList(Context context) {
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
        File mediadir = cw.getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        filelist = mediadir.listFiles();
        if (filelist != null)
        {
            for ( int i = 0;i<filelist.length;i++)
            {
               Log.i("FOKKER", filelist[i].getName());
               Log.i("FOKKER", filelist[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        currentMedia = 0;

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    playMedia(currentMedia);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateMediaTask(final MainActivity a) throws IOException, JSONException {
        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec. 
        int period = 3000; // repeat every 10 minutes. 60000 
        Timer timer = new Timer(); 
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { 
            public void run()  { 
                new updateFiles(a).execute(getBaseContext(),"update");
            } 
        }, delay, period); 
    }

    private void downloadMedia(Context context) throws IOException, JSONException {
        new updateFiles(this).execute(context,"new");
    }

}
```

This is the **updateFiles** class:

```
public class updateFiles extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Long> {



     public MainActivity activity;

        public updateFiles(MainActivity a) { activity = a;}

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Object... params) {
        Context context = (Context) params[0];
        String method = (String) params[1];
        File mediadir = context.getDir("tvr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        JSONArray channels = Json.getJson("http://192.168.2.136:8080/rest/channel/"+ linkid +"/"+ username, "GET");
        try {
            for (int i=0; i < channels.length(); i++) { 
                JSONObject channel_data = channels.getJSONObject(i);
                String channelID = channel_data.getString("ChannelID").toLowerCase();
                JSONArray json = Json.getJson("http://192.168.2.136:8080/rest/program/"+ linkid +"/"+ username +"/" + channelID, "GET");
                try {
                    for (int j=0; j < json.length(); j++) { 
                        JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(j);
                        String name = json_data.getString("Name").toLowerCase();
                        name = name.replace("-", "_");
                        if (name.contains("mp4") || name.contains("png") || name.contains("jpg") || name.contains("jpeg")) {
                            if (name.contains("mp4")) {
                                name = "/video_"+name;
                            } else if (name.contains("png") || name.contains("jpg") || name.contains("jpeg")) {
                                name = "/image_"+name;
                            }
                            String _name = name.replace("/", "");
                            File file = new File(mediadir, _name);
                            if(file.exists()) {
                                Log.i("FILE FOUND", _name);
                            } else {
                                new Download().execute(context, name, "http://192.168.2.136:8080/rest/transfer/"+ linkid +"/"+ username +"/" + json_data.getString("ID"));
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("UPDATEFILES done", method);
        if ( method == "new" ) {
            Log.i("XXX", "This is a new method, so play now");
            activity.createPlayList(context);
        } else {
            Log.i("XXX", "This is a update method, so just update, dont play again. Go on playing");
//          activity.filelist = mediadir.listFiles();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

The **Log**:

```
02-21 16:16:13.429: I/FILE FOUND(24010): video_tvr_webtrailer2.mp4
02-21 16:16:13.429: I/FILE FOUND(24010): video_tvr_consumerintro.mp4
02-21 16:16:13.429: I/JSON(24010): http://192.168.2.136:8080/rest/program/70c8223f-e054-4f33asd3f7d7/asdco/6cfbasdbe-a16600d5ac24
02-21 16:16:13.476: D/JSON result(24010): [{"ChannelID":"6casdd2-47f3-95be-a16600d5ac24","ChannelPath":"\\asda","DateChanged":"2\/15\/2013 10:59:20 AM","DateCreated":"2\/15\/2013 12:58:59 PM","ID":"5e25edasd-b82b-a16600d5f4ef","LastWriteUTC":"\/Date(1352527205000+0200)\/","Name":"Video_05-safety-ccw_mynhardt.wmv","Size":125727228}]
02-21 16:16:13.476: I/JSON(24010): **http://192.asd0/rest/program/7asd4-4f33-9b6b-a1660asd89-be1a-a16600e0bcee**
02-21 16:16:13.523: **D/JSON result(24010): []**
02-21 16:16:13.523: **I/UPDATEFILES done(24010): update**
02-21 16:16:13.523: I/XXX(24010): **This is a update method, so just update, dont play again. Go on playing**
```

Comment: I think I see the problem, probably because of the timer part, I think that should be in a new thread?

Comment: If I replace the part new updateFiles(a).execute(getBaseContext(),"update"); with new a Log entry, its works. So its when it calles the updateFiles again.

Comment: do not call `downloadMedia(this);`, calling `updateMediaTask(this);` should be enough. Also you are scheduling your timer for every 3 seconds after 1 second initial delay !! is that what you want ? Please check your `int period = 3000;` line and replace it with `int period = 10*60*1000;` for 10 minute delay.

Comment: No, its just for testing that its 3000 :-) ! Let me try this

Comment: don't ever compare `String`s using `==` operator. Use `method.equals("new");` instead in your `doInBackground()` method.

Comment: Still not sure why this is happening

Comment: I dont understand why the playback would stop. can you replicate this?

Comment: Ah I think I have it. Its the Json class that is doing this!

Comment: It was not that!! man. the task executes everything. But once it is done, the for some reason the media player is interupted!!!

Comment: is your problem got solved ?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked quite a while ago. But the solution to the issue is not Async task but creating a MediaPlayer field in class rather than making it as a local variable to any method.

Currently in your case its a part of  private void playMedia() method. Due to this being in a method, it is eligible for garbage collection as soon as the method finishes. Do something like this : -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

   private MediaPlayer pl;  // This makes sure mediaplayer is there if activity is alive
```

Answer (score 1):

Release media player when no use by `mp.release();`.
It will solve your problem.

For ex.

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {    
        mp.release();
    }
});
```